# How to implement the system lock screen in your own android app?

Tags: android, lockscreen

How should we implement the system lock screen on my own android app just like that used in GooglePay, PayTM, PFA the image.[image]

Answer (score 6):

Android has something known as KeyGuard.
Keyguard basically refers to the code that handles the unlocking of the phone. It was initially developed for the phone which had a keypad.

Tez, Paytm, etc uses Keyguard API provided by Android to secure the app.

You can implement this by following the steps:

1. Android provides [KeyguardManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html) to implement authentication.

   ```
   KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
   ```
2. Create an intent to request for authentication.

   ```
   Intent screenLockIntent = keyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(title, description);
   ```

   Here, Title and description are for displaying to user the information while authenticating. API level 21 is required for this method.
3. You can call startActivityForResult which will return a result whether the authentication is successful.

   ```
   startActivityForResult(screenLockIntent, LOCK_REQUEST_CODE);
   ```

   This throws an exception if lock screen is not set up. You have to handle the situation manually.
4. Check the result in onActivityResult

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       if(LOCK_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode){
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               //Authentication is successful
           } else {
               //Authentication failed
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, if this is how it is implemented, isn't it very unsafe? The whole concept of RSA is missing from this solution, right?

Comment: @Sid, Android manages all the security aspect. It calls `onActivityResult` function with `RESULT_OK` as resultCode only if it knows that authentication is successful.

Comment: @eshwarms, What if the device doesn't have lock set up? In that case, how does Keyguard API is used by Tez to create a device lock?

Comment: Is there any way to track the failed attempts for pin or pattern?